# Ubuntu 20.04 loads 2 sounds when booted?

Tags: boot, sound, 20.04

In 18.04 It was only a sound, but now sometimes two sounds are played.

I looked into

`/usr/share/sounds` folder but not a single file matched with the sound.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you hear these sounds when the login is completed/reached, or are you talking about a sound heard in the GRUB?

Comment: I hear one when the login screen loads.Second one is heard just after that.Grub sound is disabled.

Comment: Can you give us a short video if possible?

Comment: The problem has been gone.I think updating the device fixed it.

Comment: Okay. Don't forget to resolve your question by putting the solution in an answer and marking it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating packages solved the issue. I think, the first sound was caused by power chord pluging or unpluging.